# sharepoint2010 change field values programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a list with column "IsGood".

I have a function that update all the values of this column to "False" by ProcessBatchData();

Because I need to update 40000 records, it take me a lot of time to do this update (and I need to do it every time I operate the function).

My code:

```
SPWeb web = SPUtilities.GetCurrentWeb();
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i += LIMIT)
{
    string batch = BuildBatch(rows, listId, i, isNew);
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    string ret =
    web.ProcessBatchData(batch);
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    int a = 9;
}
```

Is there a way to do it at one glance?

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can Batch Update the data. See this How To:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc404818(v=office.12).aspx

I would be able to help more only if you post some code.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I used batch update data but it still took something like 10 minutes. I added the code to my question